# php code to load javascript array from database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I try to load auto populate textbox from javascript array function

plz suggest me how to fetch data in javascript function based php pdo sql.

I need to load this tags from sql database..plz suggest me how to do this...

this is my php code.

```
<?php
$book_no2 = $load_book["book_no"];
$receipt = $database->getRows("SELECT DISTINCT receipt_no FROM scheme_master WHERE book_no2 = :book_no2", array(':book_no2'=>$book_no2));  
?>
```

I need to load below availableTags  from above  $receipt Result set....plz help me

```
<script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
"ActionScript",
"AppleScript",
"Asp",
"BASIC",
"C",
"C++",
"Clojure",
"COBOL",
"ColdFusion",
"Erlang",
"Fortran",
"Groovy",
"Haskell",
"Java",
"JavaScript",
"Lisp",
"Perl",
"PHP",
"Python",
"Ruby",
"Scala",
"Scheme"
];
```

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand your question.

Comment: i need to load this function from database...thats..it...now I hardcode some tags in jquery fucntion...i need this from database...

Comment: i need  var availableTags = [
"ActionScript",
"AppleScript",
"Asp",   ];   this array from database...

Comment: Ah, I think I start to understand: You need to generate javascript in PHP based on data received from a database. Right?

Comment: yes sir....you are correct...exactly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if the javascript is within php page:

```
<script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
<?php foreach($receipt AS $r=>$value){
echo '"'.$value.'"';
if($r != count($receipt)-1) { echo ", ".PHP_EOL; }
}?>

];
</script>
```

Comment: but when i put this code  this not working and when i put hardcoded tags there it works ...plz whats the problem... can you load this from normal php pdo code

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
<?php

$book_no2 = $load_book["book_no"];
$query    = "SELECT DISTINCT receipt_no 
             FROM scheme_master 
             WHERE book_no2 = :book_no2";
$receipt  = $database->getRows($query, array(':book_no2' => $book_no2));  

// create tag list
$tags = '';
foreach ($receipt AS $row) {
$tags .= '"'.$row->receipt_no.'",'.PHP_EOL;
}
$tags = substr($tags,0,-2);

// write javascript
echo "<script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
$tags
];
</script>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an external PHP file and call it to jQuery ajax function. so you can get those tags

for example

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'tags.php',
    success: function(data) {
        var exploded = data.split("|");                     
        ...
    }
});
```

In php file

```
<?php
$book_no2 = $load_book["book_no"];
$receipt = $database->getRows("SELECT DISTINCT receipt_no FROM scheme_master WHERE book_no2 = :book_no2", array(':book_no2'=>$book_no2));  
$output = '';
foreach($receipt as $rec){
    $output .= $receipt->receipt_no.'|';  // Since I'm not familiar with PDO SQL, I'm not sure of this syntax
}
echo $output
?>
```

It's a very rough example, there are many other ways to process the data. For example I prefer to use JSON, I echo the data in PHP using the json_encode function & read it from jquery using jsonparse functions.

Hope it helps